# Reset input border

Tags: css

Is there a way to reset the border of an input to its default? Using [`initial`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-3/#initial) is supposed to do just that but instead removes the border completely.

```css
.textinputs {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#txtReset {
  border: initial;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textinputs" value="hello" />
<input id="txtReset" class="textinputs" type="text" value="world" />
```

The `textinputs` class can't be removed as it's set through a server control (the inputs are server controls rendered with the class).

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351217/reset-styles-for-input-elements-and-restyling-to-bring-back-the-default-appearan) is outdated and no longer valid as we now have the `initial` keyword.

Comment: why are you using border to input type=text, just add id to that use css on that only

Comment: @Rupal the css is set elsewhere and I can't change it. I can only override txtReset.

Comment: then add  border: 1px solid #ccc; to the world

Comment: Are you trying to set it back to the browser default, or to some other default?

Comment: @JasonAller I'm trying to set it to the browser default.

Comment: why can't the input[type='text'] style be removed?

Comment: @Pixelomo I've updated the question to better point out my problem.

Comment: @Pixelomo I believe the answer in the duplicate was given before the introduction of `initial` in CSS3. I was hoping that there would be a way to get it done with `initial`.

Comment: yeah there really should be a way to do it but it sadly doesn't appear to be part of the CSS specs, I guess because those styles are set by browser vendors. Why can't you update the server controls and remove the classes?

Comment: The spec _does_ have a way to do it which is `initial`. Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected. The server controls are third party therefore can't be changed. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score -1):

You can redefine css for world textbox like:-

```
#txtReset {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#txtReset {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="hello" />
<input id="txtReset" type="text" value="world" />
```